# Navbar moves down with the heading

Tags: html, css

Following is  the codepen link  https://codepen.io/greysniper/pen/NABKRW

```
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <div class="wrap">
          <img src="images/header-logo.png" alt="header-img">
           <nav id="navbar">
               <a href="#">Home</a>
               <a href="#">Services</a>
               <a href="#">About</a>
               <a href="#">Skills</a>
               <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
               <a href="#">Contact</a>
           </nav>
       </div>
   </header>

   <h1>PLANUS DESIGN</h1>
```

If you need to know something more than tell me because im only a beginner!

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Do you not want your nav to move with the header?

Comment: add a border to your body tag

Comment: If you want the header to move with the navbar, just put the h1 inside the header tag. The way it is now, the header is fixed to the top of the screen at all times, and the h1 is relative to the document. If you REALLY want h1 to be outside the header, make it fixed as well.. (I really don't understand what you're asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the old collapsing margins problem.
Since the first element has `position: fixed`, it doesn't partake in the document flow. Therefore the h1, although it comes after, counts as the first element, and therefore its top margin collapses with the body's top margin.

Now I say "collapse", but that is an unfortunate phrase which causes a lot of confusion. In reality, nothing is collapsed and the body "inherits" the top margin from the h1.

So possible solutions are: use a padding, not a margin, for the h1

```css
* {margin:0}
header {
  background:#bbb;
  position:fixed; height:80px; width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}

h1 {
  padding-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>The header</header>
<h1>The h1</h1>
```

or, give the fixed navbar an explicit `top:0`.

```css
* {margin:0}
header {
  background:#bbb;
  position:fixed; height:80px; width:100%;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>The header</header>
<h1>The h1</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps explain your question more exactly? If you want to add the `<h1>` heading to the header you can use this:

```js
        function Scroll(){
            var top = document.getElementById("header");
            var top2 = document.getElementById("navbar");
            var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
            if(ypos > 187){
                top.style.height = "60px";
                top2.style.lineHeight = "60px";
            }
            else{
                top.style.height = "80px";
                top2.style.lineHeight = "80px";
                }
        }
    window.addEventListener("scroll",Scroll);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

body {
    height: 2000px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

html {
    background: url("../images/header_bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: "Lato", serif;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(55, 76, 93, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

header img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #0ccbbb;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
       <div class="wrap">  
         <img src="images/header-logo.png" alt="header-img">
          <nav id="navbar">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Skills</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
       </div>
       <h1>PLANUS DESIGN</h1>  
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```